# How can I find owner of Azure Container Registry Image

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I am managing one Azure Container Registry which is having good amount of repository and image inside. Time-to-time I see some security issue with few images for which I need to reach out to image owner to fix it, but I don't know how to find owner of the image. Is there any way I can find owner of ACR Image or ACR repo at least?

Also, is there a way we can set image owner while pushing image from pipeline?

Cheers
Den

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACR does not record who **owns** an image.

The activity log records who pushed the image to the repository. Activity logs are kept for 90 days by default.

A strategy is to add labels to images when they are pushed.